# Programm gcc/g++ not found in PATH - Eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)

Tags: c, gcc, g++, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I have Eclipse on Windows 10, I installed MinGW and I'm trying to run a C project.
Path variable is setup correctly. I tried each solution I found online and I ended up in installing Msys as well, setting up its path variable, adding the path variable into eclipse and many other things.

I'm going mad since the two errors don't disappear and I wanted to ask if I can still compile and run my projects or not. I created an hello world sample project and it worked but running my project does not work at all. I can post all the screenshots and code you need but since there's a lot of stuff I will wait for your requests in order to avoid unnecessary information.

Update:
gcc -v command works and shows compiler information.

Environment User Variables:
[image]

Environment System Variables:
[image]

Eclipse variables:
[image]

Installed MinGW packages:
[image]

Comment: When you take the time to post a question like this, try to put yourself in the perspective of the people viewing it.  You did a good job of describing your problem, but have provided zero information that would help anyone wanting to help the ability to do so.  I suggest editing your post to include specifics with details enough to for someone not sitting at your workstation to know what your configuration is, where your file are located in relation to your project, your makefile, or details about the Eclipse settings, etc, etc.

Comment: Added some screenshots, I don't know what's a makefile; Eclipse is on fresh install so everything is set on default value; I don't think the location of my files is related to the problem, moreover MinGW is installed as default under C directory. Are there any other relevant information I should add?

Answer (score 0):

Found out there was a strange problem within my project that wouldn't let me see the output so I thought there was just a running problem.

Apparently everything works fine, the errors are still there but it seems like they do not interfere with compiling and running processes.